# Getting wrong keyboard frame with auto-completion

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I trying to adjust my layout using the `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to get notified when the keyboard changes frame. My function that adjust the layout is getting called properly and works well unless the auto-completion feature is off.

```
    func keyboardFrameChanged(notification : NSNotification)
    {
        println("Keyboard frame changed")

        var rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue())!
        println(rect)
    }
```

The values I am getting for the variable `rect` are `(0.0, 500.0, 414.0, 236.0)` when the auto-completion is on and `(0.0, 465.0, 414.0, 271.0)` when the auto-completion is off, which should be the inverse. I don't get why the values are switched. Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

After some more looking into it, I found out that it's not only with the auto-correction that I get the wrong frame, it's basically at each call of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`:

```
var rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue())!
```